# Jenkins - See SVN changes before build

Tags: svn, build, jenkins, hudson

I'm searching for some plugin, some way, to show the user (the ones that uses manual build) of our Jenkins the last SVN changes, to be more specific, what will be built if he pushes the play button.

Searching stackoverflow i´ve found some answers that looks like what I want, but aren't exactly what I need...

[Can a Hudson job poll a SCM without pulling code down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463877/can-a-hudson-job-poll-a-scm-without-pulling-code-down)

This one is saying to create a new job.. I could do that, but afraid that the user will get lost somehow, having two projects, one to see what will be built and one to actually build it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this Subversion Release Manager plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Release+Manager

Look at the screenshot in that link.
It allows you to see all SVN revisions, and then select from which revision to build

Comment: Docs are not so good, but need to go to Release page to choose the rev you want to build. Functionality is great - even has a way to choose how many revisions to show.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done it, but it looks like the Build Pipeline plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) will do what you want.  We use this plugin for its views - I noticed it also adds a "Manually Execute Downstream Project" option to build steps.

You still create two jobs, one to poll and one to build.  Have the build job identified as a manual execution downstream project from the polling job, and you're done.  I think.

Comment: I would vote this answer up, but cannot (I don't have enough reputation)... the plugin is not exactly what I wanted, but interesting anyway...